# Get answer from Jquery dialog opened and close it

Tags: jquery, jdialog

I've this modal dialog HTML:

```
<div id="exit_without_save" style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center"
    title="CANCEL EVENT">
</div>
```

And when I click close button in jQuery dialog another jQuery dialog open in this way:

```
    function verifyEmptyFields()
    {   
      $("#exit_without_save").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 116,
            width: 577
        });

         /*
       part of checking empty fields return noempty = true if one of fields is not empty
    */
      if(noempty)
    {
         $("#exit_without_save").dialog("open");
            $("#exit_without_save").html("<span class='testoAttenzione'>Warning!</span><br><span class='testoMessaggio'>There are no empty fields. Do you really want exit without save them?</span><br /><a id='bYes' class='bYesNoClass' style='cursor:pointer'>SI</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='bNo' class='bYesNoClass' style='cursor:pointer'>NO</a>");

    }
}
```

How can I get the bNo or bYes clicked answer? The dialog return true (clicked yes) or return false (clicked no).
Thanks
Markus

Comment: `onclick='cancellaEvento(" + idEventooDaEliminare + ", this.id); return false;'`

Comment: onclick function was wrong.... how can i return true or false. When this modal dialog open return [object object].... when i put return false or true on click.... why?